# Loop Formula Across Columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formula

I'd like to loop a formula across columns and have it stop when it gets to the last column that I have defined. Here is the code:

```
Sub LoopAcrossCols()
Dim LastCol As Integer
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Column = 3
Do
Cells(2, Column).Formula = "=B2+C3"

Row = Row + 1

Loop Until LasCol

End Sub
```

Just to be clear, the formula would change as the loop goes from column to column. I'm just not sure how to format `"=B2+C3"` to achieve this. I'm open to any other more efficient looping process or way to make any part of the code more efficient. Also, I'm not sure if "`Loop Until LasCol`" is a valid end to the loop. Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are incrementing *Row* but your loop's condition is based on *Column*. I've made some assumptions with the following.

```
Sub LoopAcrossCols()
    Dim c As Long, lc As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For c = 3 To lc
            .Cells(2, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1], R[1]C)"
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Alternate method of filling range with formula without loop.

```
Sub LoopAcrossCols2()
    Dim lc As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Cells(2, 3).Resize(1, lc - 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1], R[1]C)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeeped, it worked. I was wondering if you could explain the "=SUM(RC[-1], R[1]C)"? I've never used R1C1 notation. Also, for the sake of example, if looping down rows, the formula could be formatted as follows `Cells(row, 3).Formula = "=A" & row & "*B" & row`. Could this format (somewhat altered of course) be used when looping across rows instead of R1C1 notation?

Comment: @user3242245 - The R1C1 style can make it easier to create a formula with relational addresses in VBA. RC[-1] means 'whatever row you are currently on × one column to the left' so if you are starting at C2 you would be referring to B2. R[1]C is one row down × whatever column you are on so C3. You can also add all formulas at once if you specify the range. This is faster than looping. I've edited my reply and added the alternative method.